# How to delete records in Cassandra using the Python API?

Tags: python, cassandra

How can I delete records in Cassandra using Python?

I am using `cassandra-driver` and accessing my data with the object mapper API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to call `.delete()` on the instance of the object that is returned by model. See [driver documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/3.18/api/cassandra/cqlengine/models/#cassandra.cqlengine.models.Model-methods), and [example](https://github.com/datastax/python-driver/blob/master/tests/integration/cqlengine/model/test_updates.py#L272).